# How client code using "Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault" SDK manages to get Azure AD token to authenticate itself with Azure keyvault to retrieve secret?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

Below code written on top of "Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault" SDK,

```
using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault;   
public class MyAzKeyVaultclass
{

 private readonly IKeyVaultClient _vaultClient;
 public static ClientAssertionCertificate certAssertion { get; set; }
 public MyAzKeyVaultclass()
    {
        _vaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(GetADTokenAsync);
    }

 private async Task<string> GetADTokenAsync(string authority, string resource, string scope)
    {           
        var context = new AuthenticationContext(authority, TokenCache.DefaultShared);
        var result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, certAssertion);
        return result.AccessToken;
    }

 public async Task<string> GetSecretValueFromKeyVaultAsync(string name, X509Certificate2 certificate)
    {
     certAssertion = new ClientAssertionCertificate(azureADApplicationId, certificate);            
     var result = await _keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(azkeyVaultUrl, name);
     return result.Value;
    }
}
```

Calling GetSecretValueFromKeyVaultAsync(secretName) returns the secret value & it's working fine.

But would like someone to demystify how this code works.

Basically Im supplying only "azureADApplicationId" &  "certificate". No tenant, No managed identity or other details etc.

This client code running on some Azure VM on some Azure tenantX. Whereas Azure AD application with id = 'azureADApplicationId' belongs to different tenantY. With this set up, how client code still manages to get Azure AD token to authenticate itself with keyvault to retrieve secret? How this cross tenant call/authorization achieved?

Is "Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault" SDK doing some behind screen magic using IMDS of VM where client code running? or it uses "DefaultAzureCredential" class?

P.S: 1)AzureADApplication & Azure KeyVault belongs to same tenant 2)azureADApplicationId added to target keyvault accesspolicy.

Comment: I would appreciate an evaluation on this and to mark it as answered if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It doesn't matter **where** this application is executing as it is executing in the context of the application which is registered in the same tenant as the key vault.
2. You've supplied enough information to get a token:

   - Key Vault endpoint
   - Application Id (similar to a username, but for an application)
   - Client Certificate (substitute for a password)
3. The client *always* makes a call to the Key Vault first. If there is a cached access token, it sends that along and should get back the requested secret (or other object).  However, if no access token is supplied (or it's expired), the Key Vault responds with the authorization endpoint. See this response from a Key Vault:[image]

4. Now the application has all of the required parts to get an access token, so it makes the request to the auth endpoint to do so.
5. It stores the returned access token in memory to be used for the current request and all future requests.

I have written about this on my blog:
https://azidentity.azurewebsites.net/post/2019/07/31/key-vault-client-why-am-i-seeing-http-401

Comment: @ Matt Small, What are "all of the required parts to get an access token" from ms oauth endpoint for client_credential grant type? (I guess that's the grantype used by keyvault SDK)

Comment: You need three parts:
1) Tenant (not needed for a multi-tenant app)
2) Client ID (also known as a registered App Id)
3) Client Secret OR Client Certificate

Comment: In my case, I'm using multi-tenant app. But without supplying tenant, how ms oauth endpoint can find App of the given App Id? Is there any documentation to refer your above statement "Tenant not needed for a multi-tenant app"?

Comment: It uses the "Common" endpoint.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant#update-your-code-to-send-requests-to-common

However, Key Vault Access Policies do not allow multiple tenants.  The access to the Key Vault can be from a User Principal, a Service Principal or a Guest in the same tenant as the Vault.

Comment: How do we handle an expired token? do we catch the exception and check whether we got expired token exception and build the clientSecretCredentails again;

Comment: The expired token will cause the service to throw a 401, exactly the same as a request with no token at all.  The client will then request a new token using the same credentials as before and then resubmit the request to get the secret.  It should all be seamless.  However, if the credentials are interactive, then *I think* it will request username/password again.  Non-interactive will just work assuming credentials are good.